# C - array address used to execute code

Tags: c, linux

If the following array contained shell code in a C program on a LINUX machine

```
char buf [100]
```

then how does the following execute this shell code :

```
((void(*)())buf)()
```

Comment: @Joachim Why do you conclude that this makes it impossible? Most JIT compilers will do something just like that. Also, I don't think that root rights are required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. It casts `buf` to a pointer-to-function taking no arguments and returning `void`, and then invokes that function.

However, that probably won't work since the page containing `buf` is highly unlikely to be marked as executable.

Comment: You'll want to use `mprotect()` to give the memory location `PROD_READ|PROD_EXEC` rights. This works on page boundaries, so I'd recommend allocating `buf` with `mmap()`.